# How to set checkbox by default checked in checkbox dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have a checkbox dialog i want to set some of its values by deafult checked.

My checkbox dialog is as follows:

```
final String[] layers_name=new String[3];

for (int i=0;i<m_Renderer.m_Project.m_Layers.size();i++)
{
    layers_name[i]=m_Renderer.m_Project.m_Layers.get(i).m_LayerName;

}


this.m_listview=new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
m_listview.setTitle("Layers Information").setMultiChoiceItems(layers_name,null,new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
{
    @Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which,boolean ischecked)
    {
        if (ischecked)
        {}
        else
        {}

    }

}


).setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
}


);
m_listview.show();
```

i have 3 items in this dialog i want to check 2 of them every time this dialog box is opened.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the following:

```
m_listview.setTitle("Layers Information").setMultiChoiceItems(layers_name, null, 
                                 new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
```

you are setting `null` to the array of checked positions.

Create a boolean array like this:

```
boolean[] checkedValues = new boolean[m_Renderer.m_Project.m_Layers.size()];
```

Set the boolean value to true for the items you want checked. For example, if you want the first item to be checked:

```
checkedValues[0] = true;
```

Then, replace:

```
m_listview.setTitle("Layers Information").setMultiChoiceItems(layers_name, null,
                                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
```

with:

```
m_listview.setTitle("Layers Information").setMultiChoiceItems(layers_name, checkedValues,
                                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()
```